# Populate select box from JSON

Tags: jquery, json

I know that there are lots of similar questions like mine, but I it seems I can't get it working with suggested answeres. Please be patient. It could be something so obvious that I can't see it.

Anyway, I have a form which looks like this:

```
                    <form  action="order-process.php" method="POST">
                <input  type="hidden" id="showForm" name="f_order[show_form]" value="0"/>
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="input-field col s6">

                    <input id="customer-autocomplete" type="text" class="validate" required />
                    <input type="hidden" id="customer_id" name="f_order[customer_id]" />
                    <label for="phone">Select Existing Customer</label>
                    </div>


                    <div class="input-field col s6">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="f_order[new_customer]" value="1" />
                        <label>Or Create New Customer</label>
                    </div>
                </div>



                <div class="row" id="existing-address" style="display: none;">

                    <div class="input-field col s6">
                        <select id="customer-address-select" name="f_order[delivery_id]">
                        <option value="">Select Delivery Address</option>
                        </select>
                        <label for="customer-address-select"></label>
                    </div>


                    <div class="input-field col s6">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="f_order[new_customer]" value="1" />
                        <label>Or Create New Address</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

And the jquery:

```
$( "#customer-autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
minLength: 3,
source: function( request, response ) {
  // Fetch data
  $.ajax({
  url: "customer-list-select.php",
  type: 'post',
  dataType: "json",
 data: {
   search: request.term,
 },
 success: function( data ) {
 response( data );
 }
});
},
 select: function (event, ui) {
  // Set selection
 $('#customer-autocomplete').val(ui.item.label); // display the selected text
 $('#autocomplete_customer_id').val(ui.item.value); // save selected id to input

 $.ajax({
    url: "customer-list-addresses.php",
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { cid : ui.item.value },

    success: function(data){
        // Parse the returned json data
        var opts = data;
        // Use jQuery's each to iterate over the opts value
        $.each(opts, function(k, v){
            $('#customer-address-select').append('<option value=' + v.value + '>' + v.label + '</option>');
        });
    }


  }),
  $('#existing-address').toggle();
  return false;
  }
});
```

So, what I am doing is having autocomplete on customer name field which works fine. Once the customer is selected, I am taking the id to get the list of available delivery addresses for selected customer. That part works fine as well. The only part that does not work is that select #customer-address-select doesn't get populated with options. 
So, this part of code doesn't do its job:

```
$('#customer-address-select').append('<option value=' + v.value + '>' + v.label + '</option>');
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks for your attention.

PS. The json response is fine and looks like this:

```
[{"label":"First Street, Weekmoor","value":"1"},{"label":"Second Corner, Weekmoor","value":"2"}]
```

Comment: Is the `$.each` loop running? Add a `console.log("test")` to be sure in your loop; and check if `$('#customer-address-select')` has a length

Comment: Yes, it does run. I even console.log(v.value)  within a loop and it is returning what is supposed to. :/

Comment: and your element `$('#customer-address-select')` really exists ? Once ? It isn't reseted any where by other call back function ?

Comment: It isn't reseted anywhere in the code. 
console.log($('#customer-address-select').length); returns 1

Comment: and `console.log($('[id="customer-address-select'"]).length)` returns 1 too ? And `console.log($('#customer-address-select').is("select")`?

Comment: Yes,     console.log($('#customer-address-select').is("select")) returns true

Comment: Perhaps tje issue are the quotes : try replace `'<option value=' + v.value + '>' ` by `'<option value="' + v.value + "'>' `

Comment: Tried, still nothing. :(
Even `console.log('<option value="' + v.value + '">' + v.label + '</option>'); `  within a loop returns what it suppose to.

Comment: `$('#customer-address-select').append('<option value="' + v.value + '">' + v.label + '</option>');` I mean, not in console.

Comment: I know, tried it that way and it didn't work. Really weird. Thanks for your help, appreciate it.

Comment: Tried it this way as well `$('#customer-address-select').append($("<option></option>").attr("value",k.value).text(v.label));` and that doesn't work either.

Comment: You don't have a weird css rule hidding the `<option>`added ?

Comment: No, no weird rules. :)

Comment: Your comment actually got me thinking as I am using Materialize css, and I took a look over there. When appending select, I just need to reinitialize the select element with `$('#customer-address-select').material_select();` and got it working, so thank you!!!